# Pay Pal API currency type

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I am new at paypal payment system...

I have seen this been done, but i donn't find PayPals Documentation user friendly...

I need to make a payment gateway system, to allow users to use a shopping cart... then they could pay the total through paypal...

so is there a way to use paypal api tell how much the user should be charged e.g: $100 or £100 or however the product(s) might cost?
then confirm it... or if there is a tutorial (for newbies/dummie lol ) would be a great help.
Also which paypal option/system am I looking to use on this occasion.

hope i have explained myself clearly... thank you .

I can use PHP, and MySQL, JavaScript/JQuery, if necessary and I am confortable with understanding them.

(BTW PayPal is the worse documentation i have ever come across lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes paypal can use a authorization & capture solution.
You can use GetExpressChecout with setExpressCheckout.

A good solution is to use a DoReferenceTransaction with theses method, in order to use recurring payment.

I have some sample but in c#.

The API ref : 
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

Comment: do i need to install anything ? because they have so many choices there it's all so confusing... and i wanna be sure i am selecting the right things. Thnx btw very well explained :)

Comment: you don't need to install anything. you can access the API with webservice or NVP (name value pair). But you have to open an account to get your merchant id to begin the tests.

Comment: `https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks#SOAP` -why don't they make it simple lol   ---- thats great thnx mate... I'll do a bit more reading now but its a great help to guide me on the right direction .